# ejabberd mod_rest installation warning & crash report

Tags: ejabberd

I've tried to test mod_rest for my ejabberd. Received 'OK' result but with warning : "Warning: undefined callback function **depends/2** (behaviour 'gen_mod')" during installation of the module. When I tried to test mod_rest that I installed using REST client, there's **CRASH REPORT** in log.

**ejabberd version** : 16.08.23

**URL** : http://localhost:5280/rest

**ejabberd.yml**

```
hosts:
  - "localhost"
  - "192.168.88.88"
  - "127.0.0.1"

listen:
  -
      port: 5280
      module: ejabberd_http
      request_handlers:
        "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
        "/rest": mod_rest
      web_admin: true
      http_bind: true
      captcha: true

modules:
  mod_rest: {}
```

**INSTALLATION INFO**

```
$/sbin/ejabberdctl module_install mod_rest
src/mod_rest.erl:27: Warning: undefined callback function depends/2 (behaviour 'gen_mod')
ok
```

**ejabberd.log**

> 2016-08-24 11:14:31.516 [error] <0.3683.0> CRASH REPORT Process
>   <0.3683.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: bad argument in call
>   to erlang:binary_to_list({127,0,0,1}) in str:tokens/2 line 242

**crash.log**

> 2016-08-24 14:42:20 =CRASH REPORT====
>     crasher:
>       initial call: ejabberd_http:init/2
>       pid: <0.3274.0>
>       registered_name: []
>       exception error: bad argument: [{erlang,binary_to_list,[{127,0,0,1}],[]},{str,tokens,2,[{file,"src/str.erl"},{line,242}]},{acl,parse_ip_netmask,1,[{file,"src/acl.erl"},{line,536}]},{mod_rest,'-ip_matches/2-fun-0-',2,[{file,"src/mod_rest.erl"},{line,144}]},{lists,any,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1225}]},{mod_rest,check_member_option,3,[{file,"src/mod_rest.erl"},{line,134}]},{mod_rest,process,2,[{file,"src/mod_rest.erl"},{line,55}]},{ejabberd_http,process,5,[{file,"src/ejabberd_http.erl"},{line,363}]}]
>       ancestors: [<0.3190.0>,ejabberd_listeners,ejabberd_sup,<0.2578.0>]
>       messages: []
>       links: [#Port<0.35648>]
>       dictionary: []
>       trap_exit: false
>       status: running
>       heap_size: 1598
>       stack_size: 27
>       reductions: 1894
>     neighbours:

Comment: update : I've solved warning during installation : added depends/2 callback function desired by gen_mod in mod_rest.erl `-export([start/2,
  stop/1,
  split_line/1,
  process/2,
  mod_opt_type/1,
         depends/2]).`

Comment: Latest ejabberd provide mod_http_api to support ReST calls. This is the one you should probably use.